# How to get size of a vector from a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, vector, size

I have class template with a vector pointer and I need to write a `size()` function that returns the pointed vector's size.

Currently my `size()` does not work properly and I don't know why.

The size of `firstView` is not equal to the pointed vector.

```
#include <vector>

struct functor {

    int operator()(int i) const {
        return i;
    }
};

template<typename T, typename Function> class view {
    const std::vector<T>* vectT;
    Function functor{};

public:

    view(const std::vector<T> vect) {
        vectT = &vect;
    }

    int size() const {      
        return vectT->size();
    }
};

int main() {
   std::vector<int> v;
   v.push_back(1);
   v.push_back(2);
   v.push_back(3);
   v.push_back(4);

   view<int, functor> firstView(v);
   std::cout << firstView->size();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to pass by reference.  With

```
view(const std::vector<T> vect) {
    vectT = &vect;
}
```

you make a copy, and your pointer points to that copy that is destroyed as soon as the constrcutor ends.  Using a reference like

```
view(std::vector<T>& vect) {
    vectT = &vect;
}
```

will mean your pointer points to the vector you passed to the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in `std::cout << firstView->size();` , it should be `std::cout << firstView.size();`.

At a first glance everything looks good and the problem you describe is not reproducible:

https://godbolt.org/z/MPCDuq.

`Output: 4`

However, in an optimized compilation the problem becomes apparent:

https://godbolt.org/z/upeGq9 with optimization `-O3`.

`Output: 1049747`

What happens is as `v` is passed as a copy, in the optimized version this copy is destroyed and made inaccessible sooner than in the normal version so in `size()` your are accessing what amounts to an uninitialized pointer.

This can be easily soved by passing the vector by reference:

```
view(const std::vector<T>& vect){/*...same...*/}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/soX36k with optimization `-O3`.

`Output: 4`

This is better not only because it solves the problem related to premature destruction of the accessed object, but also because you avoid an unnecessary copy.

As you can see in the assembly, this makes your program slightly nimbler, though this can only be really noticeable in a larger program.